# Dispatchers used with CoroutineScope() factory function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm playing with coroutines and I've tried to run the following code:

```
private val myScope = CoroutineScope(CoroutineName("my own coroutine"))
fun destroy() {
    myScope.cancel()
}

fun main() {
    myScope.launch {
        println("I'm working in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }
    destroy()
}
```

And surprisingly for me, the output that I've got was the following:

> I'm working in thread DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @my own coroutine#1

I'm wondering where did *DefaultDispatcher* come from... Because I didn't specify *Dispatcher* explicitly.

Comment: when you don't specify it, it uses default one?

Comment: **default** *n.* (dɪˈfɑlt) A selection made in the absence of an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If you dig into the source you'll find out the following:

```
public fun CoroutineScope.launch(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
): Job {
    val newContext = newCoroutineContext(context)
    val coroutine = if (start.isLazy)
        LazyStandaloneCoroutine(newContext, block) else
        StandaloneCoroutine(newContext, active = true)
    coroutine.start(start, coroutine, block)
    return coroutine
}

public actual fun CoroutineScope.newCoroutineContext(context: CoroutineContext): CoroutineContext {
    val combined = coroutineContext + context
    val debug = if (DEBUG) combined + CoroutineId(COROUTINE_ID.incrementAndGet()) else combined
    return if (combined !== Dispatchers.Default && combined[ContinuationInterceptor] == null)
        debug + Dispatchers.Default else debug
}
```

Since you didn't pass a `CoroutineDispatcher` to the scope itself `coroutineContext` doesn't have it and you did not pass any `CoroutineDispatcher` to the `launch`, `context` is equal to `EmptyCoroutineContext`. If you're not debugging, `debug` equals to `combined` and `combined` is not holding the reference to `Dispatchers.Default` and `combined[ContinuationInterceptor]` is null, since `CoroutineDispatcher` inherits `ContinuationInterceptor` and none is provided, therefore the **final returned context** is equal to `debug` (`CoroutineName` + `Job()` (provided by `CoroutineScope()` method, since you didn't provide it yourself)  + `EmptyCoroutineContext`] + **`Dispatchers.Default`**.

Comment: It's smarter (both simpler and more correct) to rely on [the docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) instead of implementation details: `If the context does not have any dispatcher nor any other ContinuationInterceptor, then Dispatchers.Default is used. `